# If $X$ is a not a rational curve, then $\dim |P|=0$ for all $P$ in $X$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, curves, schemes

I am trying to understand the following statement: If $X$ is a not a rational curve, then $\dim |P|=0$ for all $P$ in $X$. This is stated by Hartshorne while proving Lemma 5.1, that a canonical linear system of a curve of genus greater than $1$ has no base ponts.

A curve is said to be rational if it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$. Further, $\dim|P|=0$ is equivalent to $h^0(P)=1$. So suppose that there is some section $f\in H^0(P)$ with a single pole at $P$. Does this section yield an isomorphism to $P^1$? I am having trouble seeing this.

Comment: Having a single, simple pole at $P$ is equivalent to the fiber over $\infty \in \mathbb P^1$ being $P$ (or rather the set containing just $P$). Thus all fibers have cardinality $1$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @TabesBridges I can see that $f$ is a surjective map from $X$ to $\mathbb{P}^1$ mapping $P$ to $\infty$. But why does the fiber over $\infty$ having cardinality one imply that all other fibers do too?

Answer (score 0):

When $\dim |P|>0$ there exists $Q \not = P$ such that $P \sim Q$. Now use Hartshorne II.6.10.1